# mysql - query OR in two columns then return one name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about mysql query. I'm going to write a mysql query that search for 2 cases in two columns, then the return data of that two columns should have same name. My current query idea is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table`
WHERE (name=test AND `first_col` is NOT NULL) OR (name=test AND `second_column` is NOT NULL)
```

Then I've result like this:

```
| id |  name | first_col     | second_col  |
+----+-------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 |  test | [unused_data] |   [data]    |
+----+-------+---------------+-------------+
|  2 |  test | [data]        | unused_data]|
+----+-------+---------------+-------------+
```

so that I want something like this

```
| id |  name | col     |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 |  test | [data]  |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 |  test | [data]  |
+----+-------+---------+
```

event if same id but it matched with two conditions above, it should display in separate row.

```
| id |  name | col     |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 |  test | [data]  |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 |  test | [data]  | // from first_col
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 |  test | [data]  |  // from second_col
+----+-------+---------+
```

I need your help, mysql guys! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your query in two (one for each column) and combine them with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id, name, first_col as col
FROM `Table`
WHERE name ='test' AND first_col is NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT id, name, second_column as col
FROM `Table`
WHERE name='test' AND second_column is NOT NULL

ORDER BY id -- optional
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Paul! Give me few minutes to test and confirm your answer !

Comment: thank you! It worked as my expected :)! Btw @Paul could you please suggest me any article or books to improve mysql database design? I used nosql for such a long time then when back to mysql I'm really lost....

Comment: @Kai Sorry I don't know any design specific sources but I'm pretty sure there some good books out there. What I can suggest is [Database normalization on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), the official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and of course StackOverflow. Also a very good source is the [Persona Performance Blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/) - though more focusing on performance.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative without union

```
SELECT
         d.id 
       , d.NAME 
       , d.col
FROM (
      SELECT
               t.id 
             , t.NAME 
             , CASE 
                 WHEN e.xtra = 'a' THEN t.first_col 
                 WHEN e.xtra = 'b' THEN t.second_col 
               END AS col 
      FROM   table1 t 
      CROSS JOIN (select 'a' xtra union all select 'b') AS e 
      WHERE  NAME = test 
      ) d
WHERE d.col IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: actually, I saw your query has union all as well haha. But thanks for your suggestion, new thing to learn :D

Comment: my query uses `cross join` which multiplies the rows of your table by 2, there is no `union all` in this query. You may find it to be more efficient than using `union all` - but that would need testing.